# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Attempt:

We can write the terms in the series as $(-1)^n a_n$ where
$$ a_n = \frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}< \frac{1}{n}.$$

And since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$ and is monotonically decreasing, we have that the series converges by the alternating series test.

Is this right and/or is there a better way of doing it? Interested in seeing all methods of solving the above.